# awk Joining n fields with delimiter

Tags: awk

How can I use awk to join various fields, given that I don't know how many of them I have? For example, given the input string

```
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee
```

I use `-F'/'` as delimiter, do some manipulation on `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`, `eee` (altering, removing...) and I want to join it back to print something line

```
AAA/bbb/ddd/e
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ... given that I don't know how many of them I have?

Ah, but you *do* know how many you have. Or you will soon, if you keep reading :-)

Before giving you a record to process, `awk` will set the `NF` variable to the number of fields in that record, and you can use `for` loops to process them (comments aren't part of the script, I've just put them there to explain):

```
$ echo pax/is/a/love/god | awk -F/ '{
    gsub (/god/,"dog",$5);          # pax,is,a,love,dog
    $4 = "";                        # pax,is,a,,dog
    $6 = $5;                        # pax,is,a,,dog,dog
    $5 = "rabid";                   # pax,is,a,,rabid,dog

    printf $1;                      # output "pax"
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {     # output ".<field>"
        if ($i != "") {             # but only for non-blank fields (skip $4)
            printf "."$i;
        }
    }
    printf "\n";                    # finish line
}'
pax.is.a.rabid.dog
```

This shows manipulation of the values, as well as insertion and deletion.

Comment: Well, it misses the final new line.

Comment: A rather minor point, @Zsolt, easily fixed, but the _meat_ of the answer is the manipulation.

Comment: yep, minor and can be fixed easily but it can cause problems with huge files :-)

Comment: plus 1 for "meat of the answer"

Answer (score 1):

The following will show you how to process each field and do some example manipulations on them.

The only caveat of using the output field separator `OFS` is that "deleted" fields will still have delimiters as shown in the output below; however it makes the code much simpler if you can live with that.

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}
  {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if($i == "aaa")
        $i=toupper($i)
      else if($i ~ /c/)
        $i=""
      else if($i ~ /^eee$/)
        $i="e"
    }
  }1' <<<'aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee'
```

#### Output

```
AAA/bbb//ddd/e
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee" |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{sub(/../,"",$4);NF=4;print}'
aaa/bbb/ccc/d
```

To delete fields not at the end use a function to shuffle the values:

```
echo "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee" |
awk 'func d(n){for(x=n;x<=NF-1;x++){y=x+1;$x=$y}NF--};BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{d(2);print}'
aaa/ccc/ddd/eee
```

Deletes the second field.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'/' '{ # I'd suggest to add them to an array, like:
             # for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {a[i]=$i }
             # Now manipulate your elements in the array
             # then finally print them:
             n = asorti(a, dest)
             for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { output+=dest[i] "/") }
             print gensub("/$","","g",output)
           }' INPUTFILE
```

Doing it this way you can delete elements as well. *Note* deleting an item can be done like `delete array[index]`.

Comment: the only problem with this is that `for (i in a)` doesn't specify order